# fstack-protector-all parameter in linker setting for MAC OS in xcode5

Tags: objective-c, linker, xcode5

Can someone let me know why in Xcode build settings fPIE - ffstakc-protector-all-ObjC is required to add in linker parameter ? -- in MAC OS